# Not returning from accept when trying to listen to bluetooth communication - Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, serversocket, rfcomm

I'm trying to establish a bluetooth communication between an android phone/tablet (4.0.3), and  a bluetooth device, which is an earring reader (Destron Fearring DTR3E, in case you want to know, which I don't suppose you do).

I paired the phone with the reader (the reader has the pairing passcode on a tag) from the bluetooth settings, bluetooth is on of course, and now I'm trying to listen to reads from the device, by means of BluetoothServerSocket. The problem is that the accept call never returns, so obviously I am doing something wrong. The communication is done using RFCOMM.

Code:

```
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

        public AcceptThread() {
            // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmServerSocket,
            // because mmServerSocket is final
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
            try {
                // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the client code

                String uuid  = "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB";
                tmp = bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord("pdfParserServer", UUID.fromString(uuid));
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;
            // Keep listening until exception occurs or a socket is returned
            while (true) {
                try {
                    socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
                // If a connection was accepted
                if (socket != null) {
                    // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)

                    try {
                        mmServerSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /** Will cancel the listening socket, and cause the thread to finish */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }
```

Is there something I am missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason that could cause the code never to come back from accept is that, the device "Destron Fearring DTR3E" you are trying to connect to, has actually a bluetoothserver socket and not a bluetooth client, hence, the device might be waiting for you to actually connect to it, in stead of you creating a bluetoothserver socket and waiting for it to connect to your android device, you should read the specs on the device and make sure that actually is you the one that has to open a connection on "Destron Fearring DTR3E" socket...

Hope this helps...

Regards!

Comment: Indeed it did, thank you, problem with these devices is finding proper documentation.